# SQL Server stored procedure to generate sequence number starting from '1' every day

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL Server. I need to know is there a stored procedure to generate a sequence number starting from '1' each day.

Also need to know whether I can call this stored procedure in a C# method.

The requirement is that I will be receiving lot of records ,for that the sequence should start from 1 and should increment till the end of the day. Then on next day it should again reset to '1' ans so on. In the SP I should be getting the top most row(last inserted sequence number) when i make a call from C# method.

Can anyone help me on this?
Note: there will be one record in the request message i will get
Regards
Gopi

Comment: Without seeing your query, etc my first thought would be to use `row_number()` in your query and partition the data by each day.

Comment: I know how to update the sequence number but resetting the sequence number is what I required in the stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way might be to use a calculated/generated field. Something like (not tested):

```
DECLARE @StartID int
SELECT @StartID = (SELECT TOP 1 RecordID FROM MyTable WHERE DateEntered = @RequiredDate ORDER BY RecordID DESC)
SELECT
    RecordID - @StartID + 1 AS SequenceNumber,
    OtherData
FROM MyTable 
WHERE DateEntered = @RequiredDate
```

This won't work without changing the fields, table names to your local names and you will probably have to use a `BETWEEN` for the date checks. It assumes that you have an identity field (RecordID) and that you also set the date that the record is added (DateEntered). Also @RequiredDate is a parameter to the stored procedure that this will be part of.

There is not enough information to answer your C# question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by introduce a new table to store date and the sequence number.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IDENTITY_TABLE](
[SEQUENCE_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[RUNNING_NUMBER] [int] NOT NULL
```

)

Stored procedure will query this table and return next number of the sequence. Current date has to be passed to stored procedure as a parameter.

```
DECLARE @SequenceDate datetime
DECLARE @NextNumber int

SELECT @SequenceDate=[SEQUENCE_DATE]
FROM   [IDENTITY_TABLE]

IF CAST(@SequenceDate AS DATE)=CAST(@CurrentDate AS DATE)
 BEGIN
  SELECT @NextNumber=[RUNNING_NUMBER]+1
  FROM   [IDENTITY_TABLE]

  UPDATE [IDENTITY_TABLE] SET [RUNNING_NUMBER]=@NextNumber
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
  SET @NextNumber=1
  UPDATE [IDENTITY_TABLE] SET [SEQUENCE_DATE]=@CurrentDate,[RUNNING_NUMBER]=1
 END

RETURN @NextNumber
```

For the first time you have to insert a new row to the table with current date and 0 as running number. Only one row has to be in the table.

Comment: Thanka a lot!! Now how do i call this SP in C#?

Comment: If you are using ADO.net following link has a good tutorial.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310070

Comment: I know this is old, but in case anyone else is tempted to use this, it is NOT thread safe.  If more than one call comes in at a time, it will do odd things.  (Same number given out twice, resetting twice, etc)